# Cannot assign one key of a union with generics

Tags: typescript

Consider this code ([TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaglgEwgewMLIHbAlgKuaAXigHIAzCAQ2AFcAnCEqAH1MoQDcI7g4BnCAFscwJqxIAbOFxIBuAFDzQkKACFKA%20EmQBBYMDpwARjWx8APLigQAHtgwI%20sRCnRYR%20SAD4oxAN7yUEFQAMaY9sCeEABcULgKwVC8wBIQAPyxfAZwGADmCgC%20CkoEUAAy0hBaKHrZJma%20ahpVLrr6hvUQFpKVJD4AZFABiQj01HCYGVAYNIJG3IXFytAAcpgVXNVtdaZdltZ2OI5QAKI2IRI0SOZbbhFRADSkUjJePsTqmq21HbsWuAMhoFgqM6ONMLEZnMFvIiopllAACJjXiYH7GP77Wz2Y63cIeAjvYFWbFHJxnC5XCA3Vp3AmQJ49V5QNJQNYYDYtbTozr-HyxTlbHl-JalIXtDFmADqcGAAAsAMoGKiCACSCCxhwcTjx7jwhMaw2CWQYlDVCEy2TyhSgg2RYNRGGFZksXlFKnFO2lssVdBCmpxOtp%20P13kNwKCfD9lsM1thtqRKImTolvNd7ugnt%20LpJWtxwb1kVKxF19wNxGBWclXRl8qVpvNrpYzm5qb%20td9-oBxTINAwIUdUBoYAQ1C5NTb2HMAGkDoGoABrCAgZBkFsTr1dLwACmoBmny9i06ee7oMEolxi6%2022a6AG1pwBdACUQKCYQwfGQqQAdBJkLk24AAaoHKlB5DkuRQAAJH4p4HiABRJMgMFwe056XgUQHPgkUAAPR4VAP7EbCijDqO2BVp024kCaKrqiQjJkMgyAkDhQA)):

```js
type VideoContentType = 'feature' | 'advertisement' | 'live';

type BaseVideoAttributes<T extends VideoContentType> = {
    contentType: T;
    title?: string;
};

type LiveVideoAttributes = BaseVideoAttributes<'live'> & {
    duration?: number;
};

type NonLiveVideoAttributes<T extends Exclude<VideoContentType, 'live'>> = BaseVideoAttributes<T> & {
    duration: number;
};

type DurationAttributes<T extends VideoContentType> =
  T extends Exclude<VideoContentType, 'live'> ? NonLiveVideoAttributes<T> : LiveVideoAttributes;

type VideoAttributesWithStreamId<T extends VideoContentType> = {
    streamId: string;
} & DurationAttributes<T>;

type VideoAttributesWithSrc<T extends VideoContentType> = {
    src: string;
} & DurationAttributes<T>;

type VideoAttributes<T extends VideoContentType = VideoContentType> = 
  VideoAttributesWithStreamId<T> | VideoAttributesWithSrc<T>;

function updateVideoAttribute<K extends keyof VideoAttributes>(attrKey: K, attrValue: VideoAttributes[K]) {
  console.log(`Changing ${attrKey} to ${attrValue}`);
  // ...
}

updateVideoAttribute('streamId', 'foo');
```

For some reason, `streamId` cannot be set here:

> Argument of type '"streamId"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"contentType" | "title" | "duration"'.(2345)

Why is that the case, and what can I do to make it assignable?

Note that there may be more attributes to the `LiveVideoAttributes` or `NonLiveVideoAttributes` type, so this is just the minimal example that reproduces the error.

Comment: Where does the object you are trying to modify live? Is it passed in to updateVideoAttribute function?

Comment: It's in the method.. But somewhere else down the stack a few calls. I don't necessarily want to infer attributes from that objec, if that is what you intend to ask.

Comment: Hmm, I did some research on the TS issue tracker and it seems that it's discussed here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12948 — I now realize that it would not be safe if I didn't know the type of object to begin with, so I would either have to infer during runtime, or explicitly specify that I want to change `VideoAttributesWithStreamId`. Since I am basically passing the property value as-is to some kind of database function, the property *may* in fact be undefined, since that has no practical consequence.

Answer (score 1):

Because some `VideoAttributes<T>` objects may be `VideoAttributesWithSrc<T>` objects, which don't have `streamId`.

I couldn't understand your intention. However, if `|` (instead of `&`) in `VideoAttributesWithStreamId<T> | VideoAttributesWithSrc<T>` is a typo, just replace it.

If not, it is not possible for the reasons mentioned earlier.

---

If your `updateVideoAttribute` function actually modifies some object, consider checking its actual type and using type guards like below.

```js
type A = { a: string };
type B = { b: number };
type C = A | B;

function isA(maybeA: C): maybeA is A {
  return 'a' in maybeA;
}

function accessItsProperty(c: C) {
  if (isA(c)) {
    // c is A here
    console.log(`c.a = ${c.a}`);
  } else {
    // c is B here
    console.log(`c.b = ${c.b}`);
  }
}
```